# GetOpt not working

Tags: windows, perl

So recently installed Active Perl 5.10.0 (ActivePerl-5.10.0.1003-MSWin32-x86-285500) on a new computer, to run code I used to run on an older computer (Which used the same version and code). The code worked fine on the old one, but not on the new computer.

While it will run .pl files when launched in the cmd.exe, it ignores any command line arguments I add to it. This makes me think that I'm missing something so that Getopt::Long is recognized. Any ideas?

For example, when I put in something like this into my code

```
Getopt::Long;
GetOptions(\%args, "b")
```

Where "b" is an argument used to set off some code in the script, it won't accept

```
script.pl -b
```

but it will accept

```
script.pl
```

Furthermore, arguments do work if I put "perl" in front of it like so:

```
perl script.pl -b
```

Thank you for any help you are wiling to provide!

Comment: Any answer will be a guess unless we can see the code that you are trying to execute.

Comment: print/show the error

Comment: How did you install Strawberry Perl? How are you running the Perl files?

Comment: The OP is running ActiveState perl, not Strawberry perl.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. First time posting on a site for help with coding. Will try harder.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perl problem; it's a Windows configuration issue.  Specifically, your .PL file type association is not configured correctly.

You can fix it by using the **ftype** command.

C:>help ftype

```
Displays or modifies file types used in file extension associations

FTYPE [fileType[=[openCommandString]]]

  fileType  Specifies the file type to examine or change
  openCommandString Specifies the open command to use when launching files
                    of this type.

Type FTYPE without parameters to display the current file types that
have open command strings defined.  FTYPE is invoked with just a file
type, it displays the current open command string for that file type.
Specify nothing for the open command string and the FTYPE command will
delete the open command string for the file type.  Within an open
command string %0 or %1 are substituted with the file name being
launched through the assocation.  %* gets all the parameters and %2
gets the 1st parameter, %3 the second, etc.  %~n gets all the remaining
parameters starting with the nth parameter, where n may be between 2 and 9,
inclusive.  For example:

    ASSOC .pl=PerlScript
    FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*

would allow you to invoke a Perl script as follows:

    script.pl 1 2 3

If you want to eliminate the need to type the extensions, then do the
following:

    set PATHEXT=.pl;%PATHEXT%

and the script could be invoked as follows:

    script 1 2 3
```

Comment: But the OP says that the Perl files are running

Comment: Yes, the script runs but the OP also stated that it's not accepting/seeing the arguments.  That's because the file type association is missing the `%1 %*` portion of the config.

Comment: Ah, so they're running the file as `script.pl` rather than `perl script.pl`

Comment: Okay, so `perl script.pl`  with argument works. And if I understand correctly,
`ASSOC .pl=PerlScript `
`FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %* `
should be all I need to fix this issue. But, from trying it, it didn't change anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: Try opening a new cmd window.  Windows sometimes does not update the environment of the current cmd shell when making these types of changes.

Comment: Nothing. I also rebooted my computer. Meanwhile, as a double check, if I type in `FTYPE PerlScript` I get `PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*`.